# Graphics doesn't draw on Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, bitmap, drawing

I'm writing a program that renders some `Kinect` data into small bitmaps (recorded gesture preview\frames preview). I have a class that stores mapped Kinect data to screen (X = [0; 1], Y = [0, 1]); Now I want to draw the data on small bitmaps and display on my form.
The problem is "created" bitmap... It's empty (transparent).

It's my mapped data class:

```
public class MappedJointData
{
    public JointType JointType { get; set; }
    public PointF MappedPosition { get; set; }
    public int Depth { get; set; }
    public JointTrackingState JointTrackingState { get; set; }
    public bool Seated { get; set; }
}
```

Then I wrote an extention class that should return bitmap from the data:

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this RecordedSkeletonFrame frame, int width, int height)
{
    return DrawBonesAndJoints(frame.MappedJointData, width, height);
}

private static Bitmap DrawBonesAndJoints(List<MappedJointData> mappedJointData, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.Clear(Color.Black);

        // (...)
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(drawBrush), joint.MappedPosition.X, joint.MappedPosition.Y, 3, 3);

        // (...)
        g.DrawLine(drawPen, joint0.MappedPosition.X, joint0.MappedPosition.Y, joint1.MappedPosition.X, joint1.MappedPosition.Y);
    }
    return b;
}
```

After successful recording I want to go through the mapped data and draw bitmaps:

```
foreach (RecordedSkeletonFrame frame in _gestureRecorder.Frames)
{
    FrameImages.Add(frame.ToBitmap(100, 75));
}
```

`FrameImages` is my `ObservableCollection<Bitmap>` that is bound to the `ListView` (binding should work, because I tested it using some already rendered images).

Why isn't it working? I tried to find something in the web, but ppl do this exactly like me. I don't know where's the problem. Even if my rendered data is bad (but isn't I set a breakpoint up and checked values of `X` and `Y`), `g.Clear(Color.Black);` should make my bitmap black?

Comment: As per MSDN, Graphics.Clear(): clears the entire drawing surface and fills it with the specified background color.

Comment: In that case why are my bitmaps transparent?:S [edit] Btw. I tried `g.FillRectangle()` and didn't work...

Comment: How are your original bitmaps? And also... have you double checked your mapped data?

Comment: Same sizes `100x75 JPEG` files. Yes, I checked my mapped data. They are correct, the number from interval `[0; 1]` multiplied by `width` and `height` of my image to map it on. But as I said, if my data is bad, my bitmaps should be black, because of `g.Clear(Color.Black)`.

Comment: Try to debug yout bitmaps by saving them first before trying to draw them... it's maybe a problem in your drawing method.

Comment: I saved all the images and it draws everything fine:S I don't know why it doesn't want to return the bitmap. Maybe because `g` is disposed?

Comment: I don't think so... please post your rendering methods or at lease the relevant parts of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your problem is not in the pasted code part. Somehow you lose/overwrite the data in FrameImages or something like that. The using and graphics part should definitely work.